# Objective C: Retrieving contents of a folder from a server

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, directory

I want to get all of the file names from a folder I have saved on a server. The code I have now is:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;
NSArray *filelist;
int count;
int i;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"http://cheekyapps.com/cuzzins/" error:nil];

count = [filelist count];

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    NSLog (@"%@", [filelist objectAtIndex: i]);
```

If i change my URL to something like `/tmp` it works, but it doesn't if the folder is not local. Is there a better way of doing this?

**Edit**

Or is there a way to do this via FTP?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible the way you are trying it. `NSFileManager` is generally used for local resources only.

Listing the contents of a directory on a remote server is something else entirely. It is also not possible on most sites (apparently including the site with which you are trying it in your code). You should probably try to find another way to access the data you need.